# How to call api on change of dropdown value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app i have two Dropdown buttons first is select subjet and second one is select lecture no.If i select subject and lecture no then call api studentList and show student list in list view.

This is my code:

```
    class SubjectWiseAttendance extends StatefulWidget {
    final imei_no,school_code,employee_id;
      SubjectWiseAttendance({Key key, this.imei_no, this.school_code, this.employee_id})
          : super(key: key);
      @override
      _SubjectWiseAttendanceState createState() => _SubjectWiseAttendanceState();
    }
    class _SubjectWiseAttendanceState extends State<SubjectWiseAttendance> {
      String date =DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.now());
      String holder='9';
      String get imei_no => '0';
      String get school_code => 'STAGING';
      String get employee_id => 'EMP450';
      String get class_id=>holder;
      String get subject_id=>'0';
      String get attendance_date=>date;
      String get standard_id=>'0';
      String get attendance_type=>'S';
      String get hr_id=>'0';
      String get batch_id=>'0';
      String get sort_by_lect_no=>'0';
      String get Absent_Enroll_No =>new_str;
      String get proxy_flag =>'N';
      String get proxy_reason =>" ";
      String get late_flag=>'N';
      String get homeroom_id=>'0';
      String get lecture_id =>'0';
      List<dynamic> filteredItems;
      List<dynamic> filteredItemsType;
      String _selectedLocation;
      Future api1;
      var result ;
      var msg;
      var validate;
      var validate1;
      var api2;
      var array;
      @override
      void initState() {
        print('initState');
        _selectedLocation;
       _lectures;
       api1=_fetchClassdivision(imei_no, school_code, employee_id);
       api2=_fetchStudentlist(imei_no, school_code, employee_id, class_id, subject_id, attendance_date, standard_id, attendance_type, hr_id, batch_id, sort_by_lect_no);
        super.initState();
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
      }
      _fetchClassdivision(
          String imei_no, String school_code, String employee_id) async {
        var apiUrl ='https://staging.ethdigitalcampus.com/T-View/service/DC/getClassDivisionSubjectwise' ;
        List<ClassDivisionSubject> list;
        Map<String, String> headers = {

          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };
        print('api1');
        Map<String, String> body = {
          'imei_no': imei_no,
          'school_code': school_code,
          'employee_id': employee_id,
        };
        http.Response response =
        await http.post(apiUrl, body: body, headers: headers);
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        return data ;
       } 

      **List _buildFilteredList(List<dynamic> data) {
        List filteredItems = [];
        for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
        {
        String subject = data[j]['class_desc']+"--"+ data[j]['subject_desc'];
        filteredItems.add(subject.toString());
        }
        return filteredItems;
      }**
     _fetchStudentlist(...)
      Widget listViewWidget(data) {...
       }
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       body: new SafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              child: new Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  autovalidate: true,
                  child: new ListView(
                   children: <Widget>[
                   Container(
                        child:FutureBuilder(
                            future:api1,
                            builder: (BuildContext context,snapshot) {
                              print('class division');
                              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                      child: Center(
                                        child:  CircularProgressIndicator()
                                      ))
                                ]);
                              } else {
                                if(result =='0') {
                                  filteredItems = _buildFilteredList(array);
                                  if (filteredItems.length > 0) {
                                    if(_flag == true){
                                      _selectedLocation = filteredItems[0];
                                    }
                                     return Column(children: <Widget>[
                                      Divider(),
                                      DropdownButton(
                                       isExpanded: true,
                                        isDense: true,
                                        value: _selectedLocation,
                                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _flag = false;
                                            _selectedLocation = newValue
                                         });
                                        },
                                        items: filteredItems.map((subject) {
                                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                                            child: new Text(subject),
                                            value: subject,
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    ]
                                    );
                                  }
                                } }}),
                      ),
                       child: FutureBuilder(
                            future: api2,
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              print('check student list');
                              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                              return snapshot.data != null
                                  ? listViewWidget(snapshot.data)
                                  : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                            }),
                      ),

                    ],
                  )
              )
          ),
 }
```

Output:

[image: Output]

If change dropdown value then how to change studentList according dropdown value.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to be more concise and specific in the code that you share. If your problem is with a dropDown, share only the code related to it. No one is going to go through over 500 lines of code to try to find the lines that you need help with. Check the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now i update my question.

Comment: i want to pass selected subject's subject_id to _fetechStudentList() api

Comment: You have a location and a lecture Dropdown, no subject_id Dropdown. Also, you still have way too much code. It's very difficult to sort through so much code to find the few lines that matter. If you want help, follow the question guidelines and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for question format.now forgot about lecture dropdown .update code have only one dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `onChanged` of your `DropDown`, add a call to the method that calls your api:

```
DropdownButton(
  ...
  onChanged: (String subject_id) {
    _fetchStudentlist(..., subject_id, ...);
  },
  ...
),
```